# Meta-analysis on log-transformed proportions when the sample size is missing

Tags: data-transformation, standard-error, meta-analysis

I want to compute the standard error of a log-transformed proportion. I know that Lipsey & Wilson (2001) propose the following approximation for the standard error of a log transformed proportion:  √((1/np)+1/n(1-p)), where n is the study sample size and p the proportion. However, many of my selected studies provide the standard error but not the sample size. Is there a way to compute the standard error of a log transformed proportion when the sample size is missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Lipsey and Wilson (2001) give the standard error of the _logit_ transformed proportion (log odds). Also, when you write "Many studies provide the standard error", then the standard error of _what_? Maybe it is already the SE for the log odds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just noticed I can compute "n" from the standard error and the proportion so my problem is solved!